# VLC, El Capitan: Color extraction setting is stuck

Tags: macos, video, vlc-media-player

Some background:

Running VLC on a Macbook Pro with El Capitan, I set a color for "Color Extraction" in the video effects dialog (which you reach by hitting command-E).

Now, I can't set it to any other color, I can only turn it on or off.  (If I put in a new color, it just shows the original one).  Moreover, if I uninstall and re-install VLC, I am still unable to change the color for the color extraction.

Even if I delete the application, and search and destroy every single file that says "vlc" or "videolan" under my home directory (finding them with `find . | egrep -i "videolan|vlc" | grep -v Safari`)... when I re-install it still has the same color for the color extraction, and I cannot change it!

I'm a little shocked by this... it makes VLC pretty much unusable for me since this is the one thing I wanted to do, and there's this immortal setting that I can't find in any file and can't get rid of.

So two questions:

1) How do I completely delete VLC?  If I follow the instructions in their "Read Me.rtf" I still cannot kill that permanent color extraction setting, so where is it storing this setting?

...and...

2) How do I actually use the color extraction?  This is the one thing I wanted to use VLC for, to get a certain color on a stretch of video.  I can't believe this is a set once, live with it forever setting!

(For what it's worth, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257902/where-to-ask-questions-on-vlc-media-player suggested I ask here.)

EDIT: Turns out it's not an "immortal setting", see accepted answer below.  It was just a weird coincidence that the hex-value bug for color extraction would end up showing something very close to the blue hue I originally set it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can launch VLC with the `--reset-config` flag (for example, `/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC --reset-config`).
2. The color extraction works if decimal values 16711680, 65280 and 255 for red, green and blue are used (0xFF0000, 0x00FF00 and 0x0000FF in hex respectively). On Windows VLC accepts the hex values so this seems to be a bug in the OS X version.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Using decimal instead of hex values fixed everything.  I got very confused because I was going for a blue-ish color extraction in the first place, and the hex-value bug on OS X VLC would end up showing a blue color no matter what I set it to.